# Weird error/result when running code... C fdtd method

Tags: c, simulation

Whenever I initiate a for loop to give values to an array, it modifies the result in another loop despite not being called in that loop... The problem comes from epsR... somehow commenting/uncommenting it changes the result for the time stepping loop (calculating the elec/mag field). Why? When the for loop with espR in and the if statement is left commented out, the results are good. When not commented out, I get nonsense results!

Could it be like memory corruption? I don't see what could be causing the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define SIZE 200

int main()
{
    double ez[SIZE]={0.}, hy[SIZE]={0.}, imp0=377.0;
    double epsR[SIZE];
    int qTime, maxTime=650, mm;
    char basename[80]="sim", filename[100];
    int frame=0;
    FILE *snapshot;
    /* Init */
    for (mm=0;mm<SIZE;mm++){
        ez[mm]=0.0;
    }
    for (mm=0;mm<SIZE-1;mm++){
        hy[mm]=0.0;
    }
    /* Leaving this loop uncommented modifies the results
     of the loop time stepping*/
    for (mm=0;mm<SIZE;mm++){
        if (mm<100){
            epsR[mm]=1.0;
        }
        else {
            epsR[mm]=9.0;
        }
    }

    /* time stepping*/
    for (qTime=0; qTime<maxTime;qTime++){

        /*Mag field*/
        hy[SIZE-1]=hy[SIZE-2];

        for (mm=0;mm<SIZE-1;mm++){
            hy[mm]=hy[mm]+(ez[mm+1]-ez[mm])/imp0;
        }
        hy[49]-=exp(-(qTime-30.)*(qTime-30.)/100.)/imp0;
        /*Elec field*/
        ez[0]=ez[1];
        ez[SIZE-1]=ez[SIZE-2];

        for (mm=0;mm<SIZE;mm++){
            ez[mm]=ez[mm]+(hy[mm]-hy[mm-1])*imp0/9.0;
        }
        ez[50]+=exp(-(qTime+0.5-(-0.5)-30.)*(qTime+0.5-(-0.5)-30.0)/100.);

        /*Write*/
        if (qTime % 10==0){
            sprintf(filename,"%s.%d", basename, frame++);
            snapshot=fopen(filename,"w");
            for (mm=0;mm<SIZE;mm++){
                fprintf(snapshot,"%g\n",ez[mm]);
            }
        fclose(snapshot);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you use a debugger, you can quickly find out.

Comment: `for (mm=0;mm<SIZE;mm++){
            ez[mm]=ez[mm]+(hy[mm]-hy[mm-1])*imp0/9.0;
        }` out of bounds access, undefined behavior.

Comment: Initializing epsR after ex and hy somehow solved the issue (after the two for loop of ex/hy)...

Comment: @mooder So you've found a way to paper over the undefined behavior with random code changes. Congratulations.

Comment: @EOF, I'm very new to coding. I've been following a book on the FDTD method but the code appears to be buggy. I tried to debug with codeblock but I can't tell I see how it might help? The problem arises when epsR is initialized before the line char basename[80]="sim", filename[100];

Comment: @mooder No, the problem arises when you cause undefined behavior for out of bounds access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this loop:

```
for (mm=0;mm<SIZE;mm++){
    ez[mm]=ez[mm]+(hy[mm]-hy[mm-1])*imp0/9.0;
}
```

in the first iteration, mm == 0

so `hy[mm-1]` is `hy[-1]` and that's the out of bounds undefined behavior.  Meaning anything can happen, because it's accessing random data.

If you want it to be accessing the last element, check like so:

```
for (mm=0;mm<SIZE;mm++){
    if(mm==0) {
        ez[0]=ez[0]+(hy[0]-hy[SIZE - 1])*imp0/9.0;
    } else {    
        ez[mm]=ez[mm]+(hy[mm]-hy[mm-1])*imp0/9.0;
    }
}
```

Comment: "Meaning anything can happen, because it's accessing random data." Remove the part after the comma and the answer will be mostly correct.

Comment: hy[-1] would be accessing hy[18446744073709551615] (or hy[4294967295] if it's 32-bit) right?

Comment: Thanks I feel very dumb.

Comment: No. Accessing an array out of bounds does not, by the rules of C, access another object. It is *undefined*. Full stop. The C language makes no guarantees whatsoever. A compiler is not required to produce code that behaves consistently when undefined behavior is encountered. The typical saying is that it is permissible for the program to cause demons to be emitted from your nose when undefined behavior is triggered.